# Check if string has asterisk in the beginning and the end with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string, markdown

I'm trying figure out if a string has an asterisk in the beginning **and** the end.

For example: `*italic*`.

I'm making a markdown editor, and I'm fairly new to REGEX.  I know `^` means beginning of string, and `$` means the end, I just don't know how to implement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
^\*.*\*$
```

start with asterisk, contains zero or more of (pretty much) anything (including asterisk), ends with an asterisk

[**Check it here**](http://www.debuggex.com/r/XCRXcsFXx_oqaU9H)

---

or, if you need multi-line support... this will work.

```
^\*[\s\S]*\*$
```

`\s` will match any whitespace including newlines, `\S` matches non-whitespace characters.

---

and if you don't want an `*` to be in the middle you could do something like this:

```
^\*[^*]*\*$
```

---

and if you only want a single word within the asterisk like `*bold*`, `*italic*` etc... you could do something like this:

```
^\*\w*\*$
```

I think I covered everything you might have needed, let me know if that isn't the case.

Comment: I know this is old but how to exclude those with characters in between the asterisks like this hey_a_aasd, it shouldn't select the a, oh no it got parsed by stackoverflow too, just imagine the underscore to be asterisk

Comment: @Unspeakable, that really depends. Are you wanting something like "Lorem \*ipsum\* do\*l\*or sit \*amet\*" to get multiple results, the "ipsum" and the "amet", but not the "l"? You might be looking for something like `(^|\W)\*\w+\*(\W|$)`. The above examples are all checking for the entire string to match, which your "hey\*a\*aasd" would not.

Comment: thanks for the reply! Would want something thats just not a one word thats selected.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of `String#charAt()` as well.

*Assuming JavaScript :*

```
var str = "*italics*";
alert(str.charAt(0) === '*' &&
      str.charAt(str.length - 1) === '*'); // true
```

*Assuming Java :*

```
String str = "*italics*";
System.out.println(str.charAt(0) == '*' &&
                   str.charAt(str.length() - 1) == '*'); // true
```